# Google Cloud Storage upload files modified today

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to figure out if I can use the `cp` command of gsutil on the Windows platform to upload files to Google Cloud Storage. I have 6 folders on my local computer that get daily new pdf documents added to them. Each folder contains around 2,500 files. All files are currently on google storage in their respective folders. Right now I mainly upload all the new files using Google Cloud Storage Manager. Is there a way to create a batch file and schedule to run it automatically every night so it grabs only files that have been scanned today and uploads it to Google Storage?

I tried this format:

```
python c:\gsutil\gsutil cp "E:\PIECE POs\64954.pdf" "gs://dompro/piece pos"
```

and it uploaded the file perfectly fine.

This command

```
python c:\gsutil\gsutil cp "E:\PIECE POs\*.pdf" "gs://dompro/piece pos"
```

will upload all of the files into a bucket. But how do I only grab files that were changed or generated today? Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the [-n parameter](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) on the gsutil cp command:

```
python c:\gsutil\gsutil cp -n "E:\PIECE POs\*" "gs://dompro/piece pos/"
```

That will skip any objects that already exist on the server. You may also want to look at using gsutil's [-m flag](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions) and see if that speeds the process up for you:

```
python c:\gsutil\gsutil -m cp -n "E:\PIECE POs\*" "gs://dompro/piece pos/"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. I just tried to run one folder with -m and -n flags and it took about 2 minutes, so it's not bad at all. 6 folders will take about 15 minutes to complete, so this as of right now can be a solution. My only concern is that sometimes a pdf might be edited (not often, but it happens) and it keeps same name however it's no longer same file. I can upload it manually but if someone else can suggest a script to upload any files changed or generated as of today, it will be the most perfect solution. If not possible, solution offered by rein will suffice.

Comment: Something else you could do is to check the archive bit on the file. If it's set, upload the file. Once you've uploaded the file, set the archive bit to off. The archive bit will be automatically set back to on by the OS if the file is modified. This will require some DOS scripting but will solve the problem of needing to re-upload any changed files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Python available to you, you could write a small Python script to find the `ctime` (creation time) or `mtime` (modification time) of each file in a directory, see if that date is today, and upload it if so. You can see an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) which could be adapted as follows:

```
import datetime
import os

local_path_to_storage_bucket = [
    ('<local-path-1>', 'gs://bucket1'),
    ('<local-path-2>', 'gs://bucket2'),
    # ... add more here as needed
]

today = datetime.date.today()
for local_path, storage_bucket in local_path_to_storage_bucket:
    for filename in os.listdir(local_path):
        ctime = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename))
        mtime = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))
        if today in (ctime, mtime):
            # Using the 'subprocess' library would be better, but this is
            # simpler to illustrate the example.
            os.system('gsutil cp "%s" "%s"' % (filename, storage_bucket))
```

Alternatively, consider using [Google Cloud Store Python API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary) directly instead of shelling out to `gsutil`.